# Unable to install Realm via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, realm, cocoapods

I'm using Realm in my app and I'm able to install it via Cocoapods before. Recently whenever I tried to install the Realm version using cocoapods,

```
    pod 'Realm', '0.95’
```

I'm getting the following error

> [!] /bin/bash -c  set -e sh build.sh cocoapods-setup
>
> core is not a symlink. Deleting... Downloading dependency: core
>   0.92.1.1 mv: rename ./RealmSwift-swift2.0/../Realm/Realm-Info.plist to ./RealmSwift-swift2.0/RealmSwift-Info.plist: No such file or directory

I tried removing derived data, Pod deintegrate. But it didn't help. I'm stuck with this issue. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You'll probably get a better response when you make an issue on their repo.

Comment: You're unlikely to get support _anywhere_ for a 2 year old, pre-1.0 version of a software product. Update to the most recent release and start from there.